# App Rate plugin is ignoring preferences on IOS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Using https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-rate/ works perfectly on android but ignores the preferences on IOS and fails to find app in app store.

```
this._appRate.preferences = {
  displayAppName: '######',
  usesUntilPrompt: 2,
  promptAgainForEachNewVersion: false,
  storeAppURL: {
    android: `market://details?id=${this.APP_ID}`,
    ios: '####'
  },
  customLocale: {
    title: 'Enjoying ####?',
    message: 'Rate us.',
    rateButtonLabel: 'Rate now',
    laterButtonLabel: 'Remind later',
    cancelButtonLabel: 'No, thanks'
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, this was an issue with Iphone not clearing local storage when the app was deleted from the phone. I cleared local storage and then re ran the app on the phone and all good. Hopefully this helps someone.  It was running an old version of the preferences.